# Querying shared records in a ckzone in the private database returns nothing

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckqueryoperation, ckrecordzone

Swift 4.2 iOS 11.x

I must have missed something cause this surely should work. I got this code that queries the private database in a custom zone. It returns nothing despite the fact that I have records there. I added indexes to everything! I also changed the roles in permissions so that any authenticated user could read records.

```
public func cleanUpImages(zone2U:String) {
    var records2Delete:[CKRecord.ID] = []
    let zone2D = CKRecordZone(zoneName: zone2U)

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: remoteRecords.notificationMedia, predicate: predicate)
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
        records2Delete.append(record.recordID)
    }
    operation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
        print(records2Delete.count)
    }
    CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.add(operation)
```

notificationMedia is a global static var that I also use to save said records, so it cannot be wrong/different.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `zoneID` of `operation` because right now you are querying the default zone.

```
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
operation.zoneID = zone2D.zoneID
```

Comment: Are you asking me if no records are found or did you mean to state that no records are found?

Comment: Confirm the record type and zone ID you are using in the query actually match what you see in the CloudKit Dashboard. Make sure you are looking at the same container and the same database.

Comment: I mean I made the change and it stil returns no records found. If I go to cloudkit dashboard I find 13 records.

Comment: See my previous comment. Only you can tell if you are actually querying the same container, database, zone, and record type as what you are looking at in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. I was using a deprecated method to save my record.

```
let customRecord = CKRecord(recordType: remoteRecords.notificationMedia, zoneID: zone2D.zoneID)
```

I changed it to this..

```
let customID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: remoteRecords.notificationMedia, zoneID: zone2D.zoneID)
let customRecord = CKRecord(recordType: remoteRecords.notificationMedia, recordID: customID)
```

Now I find my records in the sharedDatabase on the cloudKit database and when I use the method shown above the zone set as pointed out by [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy)  I find my records.