# How to assign a CKRecordZone to a CKRecord

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckrecordzone

I am trying to make a database in which an admin user can create a group which is stored as a group CKRecord type.  I want this record to be placed a custom zone that is named after the group name that the admin user decided on.  How do I initialize the group private Record to be assigned to that custom zone (without using the deprecated function).

```
func createGroup(groupName: String){

    let groupRecord = CKRecord(recordType: recordTypes.group)


    groupRecord[groupRecordType.groupName] = groupName
    let share = CKShare(rootRecord: groupRecord)
    share.publicPermission = .readWrite

    let groupZone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: groupName)

    //Need to somehow connect the groupZone to the groupRecord

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying shared records in a ckzone in the private database returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614231/querying-shared-records-in-a-ckzone-in-the-private-database-returns-nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different CKShare initializer:

```
CKShare(rootRecord: CKRecord, shareID: CKRecord.ID)
```

The recordZone is part of the CKRecord.ID:

```
CKRecord.ID(recordName: String, zoneID: CKRecordZone.ID)
```

So something more like:

```
func createGroup(groupName: String){

    let groupRecord = CKRecord(recordType: recordTypes.group)

    groupRecord[groupRecordType.groupName] = groupName

    let groupZone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: groupName)

    let shareID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: groupName, zoneID: groupZone)

    let share = CKShare(rootRecord: groupRecord, shareID: shareID)

    share.publicPermission = .readWrite
}
```

The recordName should be something guaranteed to be unique though - otherwise you can potentially run into problems.